# How does inverse symbolic calculator work?

Tags: database, algorithm, math

I saw [this](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced) advanced inverse calculator. It takes as an input any number and find suggestion to closed forms which give a close result.

For example for the input: `0.4633300532797865327`

It returns:

```
sin(2*Pi*3/7)
cos(Pi*5/14)
sin(Pi*x) x=1/7
Re((-1+0*I)^(19/14))
Chebyshev1(21,x)
Chebyshev1(35,x)
Chebyshev1(7,x)
Chebyshev2(13,x)
Chebyshev2(27,x)
Chebyshev2(41,x)
fsolve(poly(cos(Pi/14)
```

How would you build an index for fast lookup?
What if we want to support varied error range (distance to the actual input value)

Also I am not sure what is the syntax the tool I mentioned use for its results e.g. what is `Chebyshev2(41,x)` or `fsolve(poly(cos(Pi/14))`

Comment: Make a calculator that saves all the inputs and their outputs. Perform hundreds of thousands operations on it. And reverse engineer the process. This might be your only shot, since a number doesn't know where it comes from. But, if you register where it comes from in a database, you will know. :)

Comment: @IMCoins, true if you have almost unlimited resources as google. And also if you are at google it's not a trivial question how to do it effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have enough characters, so I am answering to the comment below the original post.

---

Exactly. This is not a trivial **question**, but it is a question nonetheless. The computer is dumb, but it is **very fast** at it. It can't think, or whatever : but it will give you an **answer** related to your **question**. If your question is "10", it will need to know where to go, and where to search. A number like this doesn't help because there is an **infinite** number of answers, and you want to narrow your answers accordingly.

A simple example of infinite answers would be : 
10 =

- 9 + 1
- 8 + 2
- 8 + 1 + 1
- 9 + 2 - 1
- ...

But now, you need to give credits to some answers more than others. How would you do that ? By having a **history** of, either the users specifically (an individual), or a certain cluster of people, or just everyone.

We have very briefly settled that we need to make a **history**, but as you said : **How would you do it efficiently ?** And that's a very different question.

Here is one example.

- Register and save the data from a bunch of calculators around the web. Anonymize the data so you can't trace it back to one specific user, but save a way to know it is this user specifically.
- Save the user inputs, along with some other information (Is this science data ? Sociology ? Politics ? Stats ? Linear algebra ?). This whole will be linked to the output via some neural network.
- As for the last part, it will be the "reverse engineering" problem. Trivially, and probably too abstractly explained : if you want to reverse "10", it will know where it most went according to the number of iterations made, and path it took to get there. Using the other information you provided such as above (using cookies, or information the users would have just put), you may achieve to narrow your answers enough to have something great !

THIS BEING SAID, the answers you are asking is shown on your website...

> The Inverse Symbolic Calculator (ISC) uses a combination of lookup tables and integer relation algorithms in order to associate a closed form representation with a user-defined, truncated decimal expansion (written as a floating point expression). The lookup tables include a substantial data set compiled by S. Plouffe both before and during his period as an employee at CECM.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is that you collect a database you can query. By associating input expressions to their output, you can produce a list for values on the real number line.

In a database of `output => input` it is not possible to hold every `output` and every `input`. So a simplistic approach is to *approximate* the data. If `query` doesn't exist in your `output` set, you can simply take the nearest point in your `output`. This will work, but you'll want a lot of samples near points of interest like `sin(pi)`.

A simple method is interpolation. You collect the nearest samples in each direction and identify roughly how much influence each one has on the query. Is it a 40:60 split? A 50:50? This ratio is then used to mix those known values together. However simple this is, it's not a close fit and tends to only work with continuous linear functions.

You can greatly improve your approximations by introducing calculus. For every argument in the `input` expression, you can tinker with the term by slightly offsetting it, and comparing the `output` of the original expression and the offset expression. This produces a line segment with a particular slope which approximates the function as you change that term in the expression!

Using the slope of the nearest sample, you can move the terms of the predicted `input` in such a way that approximates how far they need to move to hit the queried `output`. By now you should have much greater accuracy of guesses. This process of comparing an output to a slightly offset input is actually a simple form of calculating a *derivative*.

With a derivative stored for each function's arguments, along with the output, you can produce very high accuracy interpolations of unknown points. Nonetheless, you'll probably want many samples along each argument's domain so that you get a wide variety of ouputs. A good number to begin with is 0.001 increments. Thankfully some functions like `sin` repeat periodically, so you often only need a small sampling domain.

In order to identify *how much* sampling resolution to have (instead of a guess of 0.001), you need to introduce the field of statistics into the problem.

Answer (score 2):

From the [ISC website](https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advancedCalc)

> The Inverse Symbolic Calculator (ISC) uses a combination of lookup tables and [integer relation algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_relation_algorithm) in order to associate a closed form representation with a user-defined, truncated decimal expansion (written as a floating point expression). The lookup tables include a substantial data set compiled by S. Plouffe both before and during his period as an employee at CECM.

Another quote from [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerRelation.html):

> Plouffe's "Inverse Symbolic Calculator" site includes a huge database of 54 million real numbers which are algebraically related to fundamental mathematical constants.

These integer relations are probably found using the [PSLQ algorithm](http://arminstraub.com/downloads/math/pslq.pdf). Also see:

- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerRelation.html
- http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/IntegerRelations/fpsac97/node8.html
- http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PSLQAlgorithm.html
- http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/cpslq.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You'd need only perform a series of random operations to the input, then you'd list each operation performed, in reverse, and its opposite operation.  For instance, suppose input were 10.

```
10 * 3 = 30
30 - 2 = 28
28 * 5 = 140
```

Now, you invert the order of the operations..

```
*3 -2 *5 => *5 -2 *3
```

Then you perform the opposite operation..

```
%5 +2 %3
```

So then you get the following:

```
140 / 5 = 28
28 + 2 = 30
30 / 3 = 10
```

You arrive at your original number 10.